# How to Thread through a split array?

Tags: python

I am using threading on a split array but i dont know how to run a code that runs through all the split arrays at once. Lets say i split an array into a currently unknown amount of arrays, how would i be able to thread them so that i can run all the threads at once.

Here's what i have:

```
import threading 
import numpy as np

the_guilty = ['James', 'Thomas', 'Jane', 'Andrew', 'Joseph', 'Peter',
           'Keith', 'David','Ronald', 'Lauren', 'Trish', 'Amber','Frank']

#This is where my problem lay, what if i want to split into 10 arrays? 
#How would i run all those arrays without making 10 more lines?

split_names = np.array_split(the_guilty, 3)

class Who_Pooped():

    def Do_something(self):
        for person in self.names_list:
            print(person+' Pooped')
        return

    def __init__(self, names_list = []):
        self.names_list = names_list
        #Threading
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.Do_something)
        t.start()

#I'm currently writing 3 lines but it wont scale well
test1 = Who_Pooped(names_list = split_names[0])
test2 = Who_Pooped(names_list = split_names[1])
test3 = Who_Pooped(names_list = split_names[2])
```

Answer (score 1):

For this I will suggest to use concurrent.futures. Now you can split it any numbers.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
import numpy as np

the_guilty = ['James', 'Thomas', 'Jane', 'Andrew', 'Joseph', 'Peter',
           'Keith', 'David','Ronald', 'Lauren', 'Trish', 'Amber','Frank']

split_names = np.array_split(the_guilty, 3)

def fun(name_list):
  for person in name_list:
    print(person + ' Pooped')
  return ''

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    futures = [executor.submit(fun, x) for x in split_names]

for future in as_completed(futures):
    print(future.result())
```

Comment: When i run the piece of code i get 3 none values at the end of my code, this is my first time using concurrent futures and i dont quite understand the docs

Comment: If you don't return anything then by default it returns none so if you have created 3 threads then 3 None will be returned. Solution is to return empty string or don't use the returned value.